# C++ 演算の順により答えが変わってしまう

Tags: c++

AtCoderの[Panasonic 2020のコンテストのC問題](https://atcoder.jp/contests/panasonic2020/tasks/panasonic2020_c)について質問します.
ACしたコードは以下になります。

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;
typedef pair<int,int> P;

//マクロ
#define REP(i,n) for(ll i=0;i<(ll)(n);i++)
#define REPD(i,n) for(ll i=(ll)(n)-1;i>=0;i--)
#define FOR(i,a,b) for(ll i=(a);i<=(b);i++)
#define FORD(i,a,b) for(ll i=(a);i>=(b);i--)
#define ALL(x) (x).begin(),(x).end() //sortなどの引数を省略したい
#define SIZE(x) ((ll)(x).size()) //sizeをsize_tからllに直しておく
#define MAX(x) *max_element(ALL(x))
#define INF 1000000000000 //10^12
#define MOD 10000007 //10^9+7
#define PB push_back
#define MP make_pair
#define F first
#define S second

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  ll a, b, c; cin >> a >> b >> c;
  ll right = 4 * a * b, left, tmp = c - a - b;
  left = pow(tmp,2);
  /* cout << right << " " << left << endl; */
  if (4 * a * b < tmp * tmp && tmp > 0) cout << "Yes" << endl;
  else cout << "No" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

次に、原因不明でWAしたコードは以下です。

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;
typedef pair<int,int> P;

//マクロ
#define REP(i,n) for(ll i=0;i<(ll)(n);i++)
#define REPD(i,n) for(ll i=(ll)(n)-1;i>=0;i--)
#define FOR(i,a,b) for(ll i=(a);i<=(b);i++)
#define FORD(i,a,b) for(ll i=(a);i>=(b);i--)
#define ALL(x) (x).begin(),(x).end() //sortなどの引数を省略したい
#define SIZE(x) ((ll)(x).size()) //sizeをsize_tからllに直しておく
#define MAX(x) *max_element(ALL(x))
#define INF 1000000000000 //10^12
#define MOD 10000007 //10^9+7
#define PB push_back
#define MP make_pair
#define F first
#define S second

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  ll a, b, c; cin >> a >> b >> c;
  ll right = 4 * a * b, left, tmp = c - a - b;
  left = pow(tmp,2);
  /* cout << right << " " << left << endl; */
  if (right < left && tmp > 0) cout << "Yes" << endl;
  else cout << "No" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

こちらでも演算の途中経過を変数に代入するかそのままif文に含めるかの違いしか無いように感じますが、何故かWAしてしまいます。

原因がわかる方はご享受いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 3):

`std::pow()`は`double`の値を引数にとって戻り値として返します。`long long`の有効桁数がほぼ19桁あるのに対し、`double`の有効桁数が15桁ちょっとであるため、誤差が生じているのだと思います。

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    long long tmp = 123456789;
    long long left = std::pow(tmp, 2);

    std::cout << tmp * tmp << '\n';
    std::cout << left << '\n';

}
```

を実行すると結果は

```
15241578750190521
15241578750190520
```

となり、最後の一桁が違っているのがわかります。

Comment: ご回答頂きありがとうございます。解決いたしました。double型に変換されてしまうことが問題だったようですね。

Answer (score 2):

調べたところ、pow()関数はlong long型を引数として受け付けるオーバーロードはないようです。
double型などに変換されますので、引数がとても大きい場合（概ね16桁超え）、誤差が発生します。

Comment: pow()ではdouble型で戻り値を受け取るので誤差が生じてしまうということがわかりました。そこで普通に ```*``` を用いて2乗することでlong long のまま処理ができるため正確になるみたいな感じですかね？　ご回答いただきありがとうございます。